# Systemtap can not resolve probe point although it is shown in probe list

Tags: kernel, debugging, netfilter, systemtap

I'm trying to debug netfilter synproxy module with systemtap.

This is probe point I'm trying to add.

```
# stap -l 'module("ipt_SYNPROXY").statement("*")' | grep send_client_synack
module("ipt_SYNPROXY").statement("synproxy_send_client_synack@net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_SYNPROXY.c:72")
```

And this is how stap script look like

```
probe module("ipt_SYNPROXY").statement("synproxy_send_client_synack@net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_SYNPROXY.c:72"){

//some code

}
```

I'm getting below error when I try to run it

```
semantic error: no line records for net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_SYNPROXY.c:72 [man error::dwarf]

semantic error: resolution failed in DWARF builder

semantic error: while resolving probe point: identifier 'module' at netfilter.stp:915:7
        source: probe module("ipt_SYNPROXY").statement("synproxy_send_client_synack@net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_SYNPROXY.c:72"){
                      ^

semantic error: no match
```

I tried some of other probe points and realized that not all probe point give this error. For example below probe works fine

```
probe module("ipt_SYNPROXY").statement("ipv4_synproxy_hook@net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_SYNPROXY.c:314"){
    //some code
}
```

My kernel version 4.14.128 that I compiled myself. I suspects I miss something while compiling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized it is an issue regarding gcc while compiling kernel. I applied below patch and it fixed.

https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/4/23/605